# How can I send a CLISP code to the Sublime text 3 REPL?

Tags: common-lisp, sublimetext, sublimetext3, clisp, sublimerepl

I'm trying to use Sublime text 3 as a common lisp (CLISP) IDE.

- I installed [CLISP](http://www.clisp.org/) and [Sublime Text 3](http://www.sublimetext.com/3).
- I modified Sublime Text 3 lisp package. (Lisp.sublime-build)

  ```
  {  
      "cmd": ["clisp", "$file"],
      "selector": "source.lisp"    
  }
  ```
- I installed several Sublime Text 3 packages:
  a. Package Control
  b. SublimeREPL
  c. Load File to REPL

After these, I can build CLISP code in my Sublime text 3, but I can't send (load) my code to Sublime Lisp REPL by "Crtl + B (Load File to REPL command)".

How can I make "Load File to REPL" package work for CLISP language in Sublime Text 3?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to start the Clisp REPL first - select **`Tools -> SublimeREPL -> Clisp`**. Then, in your Lisp source file, select **`Tools -> SublimeREPL -> Eval in REPL ->`** or **`... -> Transfer to REPL ->`** and select the option you want. I haven't used the `Load File to REPL` plugin, so I don't know how well it works, but the other built-in commands I mentioned above should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your method, but it didn't work. Actually, nothing happened.

Comment: @Larynx did the REPL start when you selected **`Tools -> SublimeREPL -> Clisp`**?

Comment: Yes, CLISP REPL starts with no error in Sublime Text 3, but I can't send my lisp code to CLISP REPL by Tools commands.

Comment: @Larynx OK, so the problem is with that plugin, not SublimeREPL. Try using the commands in **`Tools -> SublimeREPL -> Eval in REPL ->`** or **`... -> Transfer to REPL ->`**. If you want to see the code you've sent, open **`Preferences -> Package Settings -> SublimeREPL -> Settings-User`** and add the line `"show_transferred_text": true` (make sure the file is valid JSON).